# np.mean() resulting in out of memory error

Tags: python, sql-server, numpy, out-of-memory, scikit-learn

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which has 28 million rows. I am only interested in one column and would like to perform some text analytics on that column.

As an initial step, I limited my query to return about 1.2 Million rows(just 1 column having text data).

I am using the following piece of code to vectorize and calculate the mean of each column, where each column represents a word in the whole vocabulary.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, stop_words='english',tokenizer=tokenize)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(trainer)
meanArray = np.mean(X_train.toarray(),axis=0)
```

The moment X_train.toarray() is encountered, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Support_Dot_Com/PROD1_Analysis.py", line 69, in <module>
    meanArray = np.mean(X_train.toarray(),axis=0)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 790, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 239, in toarray
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 699, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

I know .toarray() converts the sparse matrix into a numpy ndarray which is eating up the memory. Is there a way to do the same thing without using .toarray()?

Comment: If X_train is a scipy sparse matrix, you can just call its mean function:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.mean.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.mean

Comment: I used the following:meanArray = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.mean(X_train, axis=0) and got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Support_Dot_Com/PROD1_Analysis.py", line 76, in <module>
    meanArray = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.mean(X_train, axis=0)
TypeError: unbound method mean() must be called with lil_matrix instance as first argument (got csr_matrix instance instead)

Comment: You can easily convert between different formats of sparse matrices, the documentation shows how (I think you can just say X_train = lil_matrix(X_train), but verify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Alexandre Iolov in the comments, just call the `mean` method on the sparse matrix:

```
X_train.mean(axis=0)
```